# Finish a jquery toggle before beginning the next one

Tags: jquery

The below works fine - however everything seems to happen at once - I want the first toggle to finish closing before it moves on to open the next one

```
$(".masinfo").click(function(){ 
var divToShow = "."+$(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
if (!$(divToShow).hasClass("activeBlock")) {
    $(".activeBlock").slideToggle("slow"); 
    $("#content .blocks").removeClass("activeBlock"); // finish here

    $(divToShow).slideToggle("slow"); // then start this one?
    $(divToShow).addClass( "activeBlock" );

}else{
    $(".activeBlock").slideToggle("slow"); 
    $("#content .blocks").removeClass("activeBlock");
}
return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [complete](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function that can be passed as the second parameter to the slideToggle function.

So your code would look something like this:

```
$(".masinfo").click(function(){ 
var divToShow = "."+$(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
if (!$(divToShow).hasClass("activeBlock")) {
    $(".activeBlock").slideToggle("slow", function(){
         $("#content .blocks").removeClass("activeBlock"); 

        $(divToShow).slideToggle("slow"); 
       $(divToShow).addClass( "activeBlock" );

   }); 

}else{
    $(".activeBlock").slideToggle("slow"); 
    $("#content .blocks").removeClass("activeBlock");
}
return false; 
});
```

Comment: Cool thanks - though something I didn't take into consideration means it doesn't actually work but that's something else I'll have to figure out. (needs another conditional statement to see if there is actually an activeBlock otherwise it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Check out toggleClass that should help with that http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $blocks = $("#content .blocks");
$(".masinfo").click(function () {
    var divToShow = "." + $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
    var $divToShow = $(divToShow);
    if ($divToShow.hasClass("activeBlock")) {
        $divToShow.slideUp("slow");
        $divToShow.removeClass("activeBlock");
    } else {
        var $active = $blocks.not($divToShow).filter(':visible');
        if ($active.length) {
            $active.slideToggle("slow", function () {
                $divToShow.slideDown("slow"); // then start this one?
                $divToShow.addClass("activeBlock");
            });
            $active.removeClass("activeBlock"); // finish here
        } else {
            $divToShow.slideDown("slow"); // then start this one?
            $divToShow.addClass("activeBlock");
        }

    }
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zxbbH/)

Comment: Cool thanks a lot - that also takes care of my "is there an active block already" issue

Answer (score -1):

You could either use:

`.delay()` (http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

or

`setTimeout()` (http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/)

in order to insert a few milliseconds in between.